# S3 Select very slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a CSV file of around 10 columns: it's the customers table in TPC-H. Size is around 1.4GB.

Just downloading the file takes around 6 seconds. However using S3 Select for just the first column takes 20 seconds.

```
time aws s3 cp s3://tpc-h-csv/customer/customer.tbl.1 .

time aws s3api select-object-content --bucket tpc-h-csv --key customer/customer.tbl.1 --expression "select _1 from s3object" --expression-type 'SQL' --input-serialization '{"CSV": {"FieldDelimiter": "|"}, "CompressionType": "NONE"}' --output-serialization '{"CSV": {}}' "output.csv"
```

I notice that S3 Select is only fast when you have very selective `limit` clause. Is this in general true? Can I expect no speedup if I am just pulling a column?

Comment: Are you accessing it via the S3 console? It is possible that most of the delay is from sending the data to your browser. Does it run quickly with calculations, such as `SELECT COUNT(*)`? Why are you wanting to retrieve potentially thousands of columns via S3 Select? Can you tell us more about your actual use-case? It is possible that Amazon Athena might be better, but I'd need to know more about what you're wanting to do before saying that for certain.

Comment: I am not using the S3 column. As you can see I am using command line. It's being run in an EC2 instance in the same region. As you can see from my sql query -- I am not trying to retrieve potentially thousands of columns. I am trying to retrieve 1 column in potentially thousands of rows

Comment: Selecting multiple columns would take around the same time as a single column, since S3 Select would need to read through the entire 1.4GB file. Compressing the file _might_ make it faster. For better performance, it would likely need a different file format. A result of 20 seconds is still faster than downloading the file and processing it on another system.

Comment: That is not true. It takes only 6 seconds to download it using s3 command line and negligible time to filter out the first column once on the system.

Comment: Okay, in that case it might be a better to download the data and process it yourself. You might also consider using Amazon Athena, which is based on Presto. It is designed to process data stored in S3, especially where there are multiple large files (but it works best with compressed data in a column-based format such as Parquet).